# Alternating the CSS class on each row of an HTML table

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a table with a loop on a `<tr>` and I want to use two CSS classes for the rows, just like the attribute `rowClass` for `rich:dataTable`.

This is may part of code:

```
<table>
 <c:forEach items="${MyBean.Result}" var="item">
  <tr>
   <td><h:outputText value="${item.attr}" />
   </td>
  </tr>
 </c:forEach>
</table>
```

How can I alternate the CSS class on each row of the HTML table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
tr.odd { background-color: #EEDDEE }
tr.even { background-color: #EEEEDD }
```

then use

```
<c:forEach items="${element}" var="myCollection" varStatus="loopStatus">
  <tr class="${loopStatus.index % 2 == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
     <td><h:outputText value="${item.attr}" />
     </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CSS only solution:

```css
tr:nth-child(odd): { background-color: #EEDDEE }
```

and

```css
tr:nth-child(even): { background-color: #EEEEDD }
```

Then you won't need to create any dynamic classes from PHP. Works in all browsers, except IE8 and earlier.

[See W3Schools info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 0):

My preferred option is setting up a counter and using the MOD operator.

`<tr <cfif RowCount MOD 2 EQ 1>class="even"<cfelse>class="odd"</cfif>>`